# what is the issue with this python code for scanning subnet?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is used to find the alive hosts using ping each host.But i am facing some problem.My Code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os 
global lis
lis = []
global cnt
cnt = 0 
print("Scanning the Subnet : ")
subnet_input = input("->> ")
subnet_input = subnet_input.split(".")
for x in range(98,105):
    subnet_input[3] = x
    str(subnet_input)
    new_sub = str(subnet_input[0])+'.'+str(subnet_input[1])+'.'+str(subnet_input[2])+'.'+str(subnet_input[3])
    res = os.system("ping -c 4 {}".format(new_sub))
    if res==0:
        cnt = cnt+1
        print("[*] {} is Alive".format(new_sub))
        str(new_sub)
        lis.append(new_sub)
print('--------------------------------------')
print("[*] ALL ALIVE HOSTS ARE {}".format(cnt))
print('--------------------------------------')

print(lis)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Ping.py", line 8, in <module>
subnet_input = input("->> ")
File "<string>", line 1
192.168.1.0
        ^
```

Comment: Are you completely sure that you're using Python 3.X? Because I would expect this error to occur only in versions 2.7 and lower. What output do you get if you create a new program with the text `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: yes i just checked the python version in my linux machine and it was 2.7
I need to update to python 3 .Thanks for the help

Comment: Side note, I don't think you need to declare global variables in this code.

Comment: i tried with non global variables but it said cannot access variable because it was declared inside a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `python 2`, what the user sends to `input()` passes through `eval()`, hence the error.

You could either use `raw_input()` instead, or switch to `python 3`.

Comment: yes i just checked the python version in my linux machine and it was 2.7
I need to update to python 3 .Thanks for the help

Comment: if you don't have python3 installed you can use `raw_input()`

Comment: @Mr_Null_Byte if that answer is good for you, you can accept it, clicking on the 'v' like link. ty